# Android compose animation (like horizontal progress indicator)

Tags: android, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose

Im struggling with simple animations using compose (couple of tutorials available, but using older versions of compose).

***Note:***
Compose version: 1.0.0-beta03

To animate the size of a view (just like a progress indicator), I have the following code:

```
@Composable
private fun SingleProgress(
    percentage: Float
) {
    val animationState = remember { mutableStateOf(AnimationState.START) }
    val transition = updateTransition(targetState = animationState.value, label = "transitionLabel")

    val progressTransition = transition.animateFloat(
        transitionSpec = { tween(durationMillis = 3000) },
        label = "progressTransition"
    ) {
        if (it == AnimationState.START) 0.0001f else (percentage / 100)
    }

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(progressTransition.value)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(5.dp)
                .background(Color.Green)
        )

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1 - progressTransition.value)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(5.dp)
                .background(Color.Red)
        )
    }

    // animate all views to END state
    animationState.value = AnimationState.END
}
```

So far so good (even if this is not the best approach to automatically animate from value to value).

Now I want to animate multiple views, did try the same approach but without success:

```
@Composable fun MultipleProgess() {
val listOfPercentages = listOf(20F, 60F, 20F)
val listOfColors = listOf(Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue)

val animationState = remember { mutableStateOf(AnimationState.START) }
val transition = updateTransition(targetState = animationState.value, label = "transitionLabel")

Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .wrapContentHeight(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
) {
    listOfPercentages.forEachIndexed { index, value ->
        val percentage = value / 100

        val progressTransition = transition.animateFloat(
            transitionSpec = { tween(durationMillis = 3000) },
            label = "progressTransition"
        ) {
            if (it == AnimationState.START) 0.0001f else (percentage)
        }

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(progressTransition.value)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(2.5.dp)
                .background(listOfColors[index])
        )
    }
}

// animate all views to END state
animationState.value = AnimationState.END
 }
```

**Questions:**

1. Can I improve/simplifiy the animation on `SimpleProgress`?
2. The composable `MultipleProgress` does not work as expected. The animation does not respect the tween duration, it is a fast animation hard to understand what's going on there.
   Whats the best way to implement this multiple progress running at the same time?

Comment: The value of progression of the weight is wrong (since you have 3 different ranges with different dimensions). Try the same code with 2 items. `val listOfPercentages = listOf(20F, 80F)` and apply to the weight:
  `val weight = if (progressTransition.value < 100/2)  1-progressTransition.value else progressTransition.value`. In this case your multiprogress works. You have to change the way of assigning of the weight.